# mongodb javascript function default storage location

Tags: mongodb

I have created JavaScript function into mongo db. Now i have to change in that function, but i can't find its location.

```
e.g
```

I have Student collection and i used this collection for increment student id.

```
        **Function**

        function getNextValue(sequence){

           var document = db.Student.findAndModify({
              query:{_id: sequence },
              update: {$inc:{sequence_value:1}},
              new:true
           });

           return document.sequence_value;
        }

        And i run it and insert some data into registration collection with getNextValue function. Its working find and give me increment value.

        db.registration.insert({
           "_id":getNextValue("studentid"),
           "name":"karan khatri"
        })
```

Now my question is on which location  **getNextValue**  function is stored ?

I have checked in system collection also but i can't find.